# Calling Stored Procedure Output Parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, cloudera

The function sign returns a -1, 0 or 1 depending on the sign of the variable testVal, but the output parameter isn't being recognized:

```
    static int callableStatement(Connection con, double testVal)
        throws SQLException {
     CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{ ? = Select sign(?)}");
     cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
     cstmt.setDouble(2, testVal);
     cstmt.executeQuery();
     int sign = cstmt.getInt(1);
     System.out.println(sign);
     return sign;
      }
```

The stacktrace gives the SQL error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][JDBC](11420) Error, parameter metadata 
    not populated.
```

Comment: What is `testVal`? Did you try with `CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = CALL sign(?)}");` and `cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);`?

Comment: I've tried testVal=-20 as both an int and a double in case auto-conversion isn't supported. When run

         CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{ ? = Select 
         sign(?)}");
         cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
I get the same error as above

Comment: Could you add a minimal, verifiable and complete example of what you've tried?

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: What about `"{? = CALL sign(?)}` instead of `SELECT`?

Comment: Same error, perhaps implying they are interchangeable

Comment: Are you possibly enabling native queries with `UseNativeQuery=1` when you establish the connection? It looks like your SQL isn't even getting parsed before you get the error about parameter metadata (`SELECT` is clearly invalid SQL for a stored procedure call).

Comment: I don't believe so, it wasn't explicitly enabled or referenced in the connection string. Would it be necessary to explicitly disable it somehow?

Comment: jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxxxxxx.com:10000/default;UseNativeQuery=0

Tried the above with no luck